# Delete function in binary search tree in haskell

Tags: haskell

How can I implement a function to delete an element in a binary search tree?
This is my tree:

```
data Tree a = Leaf
            | Node a (Tree a) (Tree a)
```

I know that in case my tree is a Leaf

```
delete :: (Ord a) => a -> Tree a -> Tree a
delete _ Leaf   = Leaf
```

and in case left and right are not empty, I have to delete the minimum from right (or maximum from left) and it became the root. But, how can I implement it??

Comment: Then please tag it so next time. It's common practice here.

Comment: @MatveyB.Aksenov oh, sorry. next time I'll remember

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should implement a function

```
delMin :: Tree a -> (Tree a, a)
```

that deletes the minimum element from a tree and returns both the modified tree and the minimum element. Then the deletion algorithm becomes: find the node with the item to be deleted and call

```
-- delete' n  deletes the node n and returns a modified BST
delete' :: Ord a => Tree a -> Tree a
delete' (Node _ l Leaf)  =  l
delete' (Node _ Leaf r)  =  r
delete' (Node _ l r)     =  let (r', min) = delMin r in
                              Node min l r'
```

Comment: If `delMin` is top-level, it is probably good to make it `delMin :: Tree a -> Maybe (Tree a, a)` to deal with `Leaf`.

Comment: @DanielFischer: `delMin`, at least in current should not be exported from the BST module. It might be hidden in a `where` clause.

Comment: It might be considered generally useful, though, so _if_ it is exposed, I'd rather safely deal with `Leaf`. If it's just a local, that would of course be unnecessary clutter.